# webpack-dev-middleware compiles twice on boot

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-middleware

With the same `webpack.config.js`, `webpack-dev-server` runs a compile once on boot, but my `webpack-dev-middleware` setup compiles twice immediately upon startup.

I've added some logging in chokidar to make sure that a file change isn't happening and it doesn't appear to be. Any ideas on how to tell what is triggering the second compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My logging for file watching was in the wrong place. It was actually file changes that I kick off right *before* starting the dev server. I'm not sure how to make it less sensitive,  but that's a different issue.

For posterity, to add logging to find out what changed, I manually edited `node_modules/watchpack/lib/watchpack.js` and added a `console.log(file)` within the `watcher.on("change"...`